# Error: 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax, php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy programando una pagina web, tengo un error que me arroja al insertar datos en una tabla desde php a mysql, pero no se la razón podrían ayudarme por favor.

las variables las recibo desde un _POST de está manera

```
<?php


  $marca=$_POST['marca'];
  $modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
  $serie=$_POST['serie'];
  $ubicacion=$_POST['ubicacion'];
  $area=$_POST['area'];
  $codigo_interno=$_POST['codigo_interno'];
  $fecha_p_marcha=$_POST['fecha_p_marcha'];
  $garantia=$_POST['garantia'];
  $man_serv_tec=$_POST['man_serv_tec'];
  $man_user=$_POST['man_user'];
  $planos=$_POST['planos'];
  $frecuencia=$_POST['frecuencia'];
  $id_datos_eq=1;
  $id_frec_mes=1;

  //la conexion la hago de está manera
  $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'tabla'); //se conecta correctamente
  //ingreso datos así a la tabla
  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO datos_equipo (id_datos_eq, marca, modelo, serie, ubicacion, area, codigo_interno, fecha_p_marcha, garantia, man_serv_tec, man_user, planos, frecuencia, id_frec_mes) VALUES ('$id_datos_eq', '$marca', '$modelo', '$serie', '$ubicacion', '$area', '$codigo_interno', '$fecha_p_marcha', '$garantia', '$man_serv_tec', '$man_user', '$planos', '$frecuencia', '$id_frec_mes')");

  //lo reviso con esto
  if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
   echo "New record created successfully"; } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" .mysqli_error($mysqli);}



?>
```

y el error que me genera es esté
Error: 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

les agradezco, buena noche

Comment: Estás ejecutando dos veces la consulta. Tienes que cambiar el `if` por esto: `if ($sql) {
   echo "New record created successfully"; } else { ...`  si usas `mysqli_query` en el `if` lo que haces es mandar a ejecutar el resultado de `$sql`, que no es una consulta en sí. Es importante llamar las cosas por su nombre, realmente lo que se obtiene es `$sql` no es una consulta, sino el resultado de la misma, quizá por eso vino la confusión al programar tu código ¿?

Comment: Ya vi mi error, te agradezco mucho, muy útil, me salvaste de una

Answer (score 3):

Cada vez que uses `mysqli_query` se realizará o se intentará realizar lo que hace esa función, que es mandar una consulta a la base de datos.

En el código se ve que mandas dos veces la consulta, primero aquí, que es el momento correcto:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO datos_equipo (id_datos_eq, marca, ...) VALUES ('$id_datos_eq', '$marca', ...)");
```

Y luego aquí:

```
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
```

Aunque sea un `if`, como estás invocando a `mysqli_query` le estás pidiendo que ejecute `$sql`, que no es realmente una instrucción SQL, sino el resultado de la anterior ejecución de `mysqli_query`, dado que lo guardaste en esa variable a la que llamaste `$sql`. En programación existe algo que se llama *convención de nombre*, y se recomienda entre otras cosas dar nombres descriptivos a las variables. Llamar `$sql` a un conjunto de resultados es incorrecto (confuso) desde el punto de vista de la *convención de nombres*).

Puedes corregir el código así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO datos_equipo (id_datos_eq, marca, modelo, serie, ubicacion, area, codigo_interno, fecha_p_marcha, garantia, man_serv_tec, man_user, planos, frecuencia, id_frec_mes) VALUES ('$id_datos_eq', '$marca', '$modelo', '$serie', '$ubicacion', '$area', '$codigo_interno', '$fecha_p_marcha', '$garantia', '$man_serv_tec', '$man_user', '$planos', '$frecuencia', '$id_frec_mes')";
$mData=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

//lo reviso con esto
$mOutput= ($mData) ? "New record created successfully" : "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" .mysqli_error($mysqli);
echo $mOutput;
```

Lo que he hecho ha sido:

1. Llamar `$mData` a los resultados de la consulta, para evitar confusiones.
2. Evaluar ese resultado con un operador ternario, asignando el mensaje de salida a una variable llamada `$mOutput`. Así hay menos escritura de código, evitando el `if`.
3. Imprimir el contenido de `$mOutput`, que será uno u otro según el caso.

Espero te sea de utilidad y bienvenido a Stackoverflow.